# Importing multiple ranges into powerpoint slide from excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am a novice to macro development. I have a macro, which imports a specific range (B4:J40) in every worksheet into a separate ppt slide as an image on a specific position. This is all fine, what i want to achieve is that this macro should import two ranges (say B4:D40 & E4:J40) from same worksheet on same slide as image on separate positions. Then this loop should continue (as it does now) for every worksheet in current workbook.

Following is the code I am currently using:

```
Sub WorkbooktoPowerPoint()

    'Step 1:  Declare your
    Dim pp As Object
    Dim PPPres As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange As String
`
    'Step 2:  Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible
    Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
    pp.Visible = True


    'Step 3:  Set the ranges for your data and
    MyRange = "B4:J25"

    'Step 4:  Start the loop through each worksheet
    For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xlwksht.Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

    'Step 5:  Copy the range as picture
    xlwksht.Range(MyRange).CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    'Step 6:  Count slides and add new blank slide as next available slide number
    '(the number 12 represents the enumeration for a Blank Slide)
    SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)
    PPSlide.Select

    'Step 7:  Paste the picture and adjust its position
    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 65
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 7.2
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700


    'Step 8:  Add the title to the slide then move to next worksheet
    Next xlwksht

    'Step 9:  Memory Cleanup
    pp.Activate
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set pp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please modify it for me as I have no knowledge of coding languages. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dear Siddharth Rout, I have this code in your suggested format but what I want it to do is import multiple ranges and not this same range that it already imports. Thanks

Comment: I was working on your code and have the code ready. I am late as I was testing the code. @taotao has already posted an answer so I guess I will have to discard the code that I wrote. Give that code a try and if it doesn't work for you then I will post the answer. BTW do you want to keep the width at `700` ;)? This is what I realized when I was testing my code...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub WorkbooktoPowerPoint()

    'Step 1: Declare your variables
    Dim pp As Object
    Dim PPPres As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange As String
    Dim MyRange1 As String 'Define another Range
    Dim MyTitle As String

    'Step 2: Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible
    Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
    pp.Visible = True

    'Step 3: Set the ranges for your data and title
    MyRange = "B4:D7"
    MyRange1 = "E4:J7"
    'Step 4: Start the loop through each worksheet
    For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xlwksht.Select Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
    'Step 5: Copy the range as picture
    xlwksht.Range(MyRange).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    'Step 6: Count slides and add new blank slide as next available slide number '(the number 12 represents the enumeration for a Blank Slide)
    SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)
    PPSlide.Select
    'Step 7: Paste the picture and adjust its position
    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, True
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 65
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 7.2
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700
    'Step 8: Add the title to the slide then move to next worksheet
    xlwksht.Range(MyRange1).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignBottoms, True
    'You can set the second image prostion here
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 765
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 7.2
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700

    Next xlwksht

    'Step 9: Memory Cleanup 
    pp.Activate
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set pp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot Taotao, it was a great help